# How to inject function to method in java to reduce code repetition?

Tags: java, arrays, functional-programming

I'm currently learning Java and during my current project I need to print stats of students depending on the different courses: "Java", "DSA", "Databases", "Spring". I managed to get right data but as you can see below in code it is to many code repetition. Do you know maybe how to inject e.g. `getJavaPoints()` function when "Java" String is passed to `printInfoAboutTopLearners(String courseName)` method?

I don't use DB as repository currently as it is just learning project the repository is ArrayList<<Student>Student>.

The goal is to simplify code below:

```
public static void printInfoAboutTopLearners(String courseName) {

    System.out.println(courseName);
    System.out.println("id     points  completed");

    ArrayList<Student> students = StudentRepository.getStudentRepository();

    if (courseName.equals("Java")) {
        students
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getJavaPoints).reversed())
                .filter(student -> student.getJavaPoints() != 0)
                .forEach(student -> System.out.printf(Locale.US,
                        "%d  %-8d %.1f%%\n",
                        student.getId(),
                        student.getJavaPoints(),
                        (double) student.getJavaPoints() * 100 / JAVA_POINTS));
    }

    if (courseName.equals("DSA")) {
        students
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getDsaPoints).reversed())
                .filter(student -> student.getDsaPoints() != 0)
                .forEach(student -> System.out.printf(Locale.US,
                        "%d  %-8d %.1f%%\n",
                        student.getId(),
                        student.getDsaPoints(),
                        (double) student.getDsaPoints() * 100 / JAVA_POINTS));
    }

    if (courseName.equals("Databases")) {
        students
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getDbPoints).reversed())
                .filter(student -> student.getDbPoints() != 0)
                .forEach(student -> System.out.printf(Locale.US,
                        "%d  %-8d %.1f%%\n",
                        student.getId(),
                        student.getDbPoints(),
                        (double) student.getDbPoints() * 100 / JAVA_POINTS));
    }

    if (courseName.equals("Spring")) {
        students
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getSpringPoints).reversed())
                .filter(student -> student.getSpringPoints() != 0)
                .forEach(student -> System.out.printf(Locale.US,
                        "%d  %-8d %.1f%%\n",
                        student.getId(),
                        student.getSpringPoints(),
                        (double) student.getSpringPoints() * 100 / JAVA_POINTS));
    }
}
```

Below Student class:

```
public class Student {

private final int ID_BASE = 10000;

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private int javaPoints;
private int dsaPoints;
private int dbPoints;
private int springPoints;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.id = idGenerator();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.javaPoints = 0;
    this.dsaPoints = 0;
    this.dbPoints = 0;
    this.springPoints = 0;
}

public int idGenerator(){
    return ID_BASE + StudentRepository.getSize();
} //Getters and Setters below
```

Comment: Think in terms of database design. If you were creating a database for a school, would you include points in the Students table? No, you would not because `points` is not an attribute of a student. You would most likely add that to a `Registry` table (you would not even put that in `Courses` table). I am not saying this is the case, but code duplication can be a side effect of putting data in the incorrect classes.

Comment: Also, get used to the idea of using Java `record` for POJOs.

Comment: I hope that you consider my answer as it fully addresses your question WITH functional code example. If it does satisfy your original question, I hope you reconsider your decision as to which answer is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would model this:

```
public record Student(String firstName, String lastName, String studentID) {}
public record Course(String name, String id, Gradebook gradebook) {}
```

`Student` and `Course` objects should not (or need not) be directly related to each other. A student doesn't have a course. A student is ENROLLED in a course. Likewise, a course doesn't have a student. Attributes of a course should be limited to at least its name and its ID. A course could have other attributes like section ID, a boolean flag for availability, capacity (max number of seats), and description. I used Java records to eliminate boilerplate code. Also, these objects are immutable (and inherently thread-safe) because there is no reason to mutate them once they are created. I can still mutate the gradebook as you will see later on.

You then need to create classes that will complete the association between a student and a course. Something that comes to mind is `Enrollment`. In this class, you will have a list of courses containing a list of students enrolled in the particular courses. For this, I will use a class.

```
public class Enrollment {
    private Map<Course, List<Student>>
    // rest of class omitted
}
```

This is an entity a registrar's office would need. For this example, I indicated that `Gradebook` is an attribute of `Course` record. This means that `Course` object has-a `Gradebook`. A gradebook is a record of students and their particular grades. This is the class that, for your example, links or associates students and course grades.

```
public class Gradebook {

    private Map<Student, List<Integer>> grades = new HashMap<>(); // mapping of student IDs and course grades

    public List<Integer> getGrades(Student student) {
        return grades.get(student);
    }

    public double getGPA(Student student) {
        return getGrades(student).stream().mapToInt((x) -> x).summaryStatistics().getAverage();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        grades.put(student, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    public void enterStudentGrade(Student student, int points) {
        List<Integer> gradePoints = grades.get(student);
        gradePoints.add(points);
        grades.put(student, gradePoints);
    }
    
    public TopPerformer getTopPerformer() {
        Map.Entry<Student, Double> topPerformer = grades.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e-> e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble())).entrySet().stream().max((Entry<?, Double> e1, Entry<?, Double> e2) -> e1.getValue()
                        .compareTo(e2.getValue())).get();
        
        
        String name = topPerformer.getKey().firstName() + " " + topPerformer.getKey().lastName(); 
        return new TopPerformer(name, topPerformer.getValue());
    }
    
    public record TopPerformer(String name, double points) {}       
}
```

It is worth noting that I didn't use a `record` for the gradebook because I want to be able to update (mutate) gradebooks after they are initially created.

Now that you have this framework in place, you can create a function to figure out (calculate) the top performers for each course. The question is: where do you put this method? IMO, since a `Gradebook` instance contains a record of students and their particular grades, you can have this class calculate the averages and return its top student. For simplicity, I added it to this class. I also believe it belongs here since the purpose of the `Gradebook` class is to manage student grades and calculating the top performer seems to be a derived functionality of this class.  I also added the following `main` method to this class to test the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student steve = new Student("Steve", "Jobs", "12345");
        Student bill = new Student("Bill", "Gates", "67890");
        Student john = new Student ("John", "Doe", "98765");
        Student jane = new Student ("Jane", "Doe", "31245");
        
        Course java = new Course("Java", "COMP1010", new Gradebook());
        Course dsa = new Course("DSA", "COMP1020", new Gradebook());
        
        
        dsa.gradebook().addStudent(john);
        dsa.gradebook().addStudent(bill);
        
        java.gradebook().addStudent(steve);
        java.gradebook().addStudent(jane);
        
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(jane, 100);
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(jane, 95);
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(jane, 97);
        
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(steve, 96);
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(steve, 95);
        java.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(steve, 97);
        
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(bill, 100);
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(bill, 95);
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(bill, 97);
        
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(john, 96);
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(john, 95);
        dsa.gradebook().enterStudentGrade(john, 97);
        
        System.out.println(java.gradebook().getTopPerformer());
        System.out.println(dsa.gradebook().getTopPerformer());
    }
```

There is no branching to figure out the course name and do the calculation for top performer. No matter what course it is (current or one that doesn't exist today), it calculates the top performer using the same function; which goes to the heart of your question which was eliminate duplicate code.

Executing the code above outputs the following:

```
TopPerformer[name=Jane Doe, points=97.33333333333333]
TopPerformer[name=Bill Gates, points=97.33333333333333]
```

The `TopPerformer` object doesn't need to be a record. It also doesn't need to be a class. You could simply modify the code slightly and return a map of the top student and his or her GPA.

Comment: The `Gradebook` class should have a `removeStudent(Student)` method but I didn't think it was necessary or relevant for this example.

Comment: this is exactly what I was needed. Thanks. I understand now that my problem wasn't one technical solution but a design of an app itself. Really good explonation for planing which classes use to solve a problem. Next time I will start with creating class model base on real life solutions.

Comment: @PatrykLewczuk I always recommend sketching (drawing things out). In my office, I have a whiteboard where I sketch and take notes and I normally fill it all out before I write any code. It helps solidifying your design before you code. Once you code and it doesn't work out the way you need, you tend to get frustrated and that will just delay your progress. I am glad you enjoyed my solution and the explanation. Don't forget to also upvote my answer as helpful ;)

Comment: @PatrykLewczuk also notice how I took all the strenuous stuff out of the classes or records. For example, `Student` doesn't have all the fields your class had. Why? To solve this problem, none of those fields are needed. Keep it simple. You can always add those fields later on. Extra stuff only adds to the confusion. My records were very minimalistic, but that helped me develop my solution much quicker.

Comment: I will vote up as soon as I reach 15 rep points. This option is not available for me yet. I already rewrite the code and remove all points fileds form `Student` class. It works well and it is simple for me to add other statistics as well now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot going on here, so without re-writing everything myself, I would suggest you embrace OOD and re-work your classes a bit.  You already have a Student class.  You should also had a Course class that contains a Map of students with their scores.  You can then remove the various point fields from your student class.  I'd also keep a CourseRepository class.

Course's have Students, Students don't have Courses.

Then your logic would go something like:

1. Get Course from CourseRepository using the courseName
2. Get Get the list of Students and their scores from the Course
3. Sort the list
4. Output the list

Answer (score 0):

Though there are other improvement areas like class design etc. as suggested in other answers. Below code demonstrates injecting a function to a method to take out specifics out of the method while  keeping only common logic inside. This method is then typically be called "higher order function" in functional programming paradigm terminology.

```
public static void printInfo(String courseName) {
    switch (courseName) {
        case "Java":
            printInfoAboutTopLearners(Student::getJavaPoints);
            break;
        case "DSA":
            printInfoAboutTopLearners(Student::getDsaPoints);
            break;
        case "Databases":
            printInfoAboutTopLearners(Student::getDbPoints);
            break;
        case "Spring":
            printInfoAboutTopLearners(Student::getSpringPoints);
    }
}

public static void printInfoAboutTopLearners(Function<Student, Integer> valueGetter) {
    System.out.println("id     points  completed");
    List<Student> students = StudentRepository.getStudentRepository();
    students
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(valueGetter).reversed())
            .filter(student -> valueGetter.apply(student) != 0)
            .forEach(student -> System.out.printf(Locale.US,
                    "%d  %-8d %.1f%%\n",
                    student.getId(),
                    valueGetter.apply(student),
                    (double) valueGetter.apply(student) * 100 / JAVA_POINTS));

}
```